# Google Analytics dailyUploads not working with using google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am using the [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) v0.7.1, ruby 2.1.

When I upload Custom Data Sources through Google Analytics API v3 with   [Google Analytics API v3 > analytics.management.dailyUploads.upload](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/analytics/v3/analytics.management.dailyUploads.upload) :

**Request**

```
POST https: //www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/**********************/webproperties/**********************/customDataSources/**********************/dailyUploads/2014-04-06/uploads?appendNumber=1&type=cost&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer **************************
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

**Response**

```
400 Bad Request

    {

"error": {

         "errors": [{"domain": "global",
                     "reason": "badRequest",
                     "message": "Upload request url should start with https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/..."}],
          "code": 400,
          "message": "Upload request url should start with https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/..."
          }

    }
```

That response I get when call this method of api from gem [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) too.

But the  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/dailyUploads/upload) states:

**HTTP request**

```
POST https: //www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts...
```

But in [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/analytics/v3/analytics.management.dailyUploads.upload) and gem request is `https: //www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3`... , not `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3... .`

Anyone encountered this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Extra info Issue was logged: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 
     user and code value 
In  authorize method.

You'll get, 
     user_ID from client_secret.json 
and 
      run the URL, you get in the console under 'Open the following URL in the browser' for code value